# Should these two tags be combined [microsoft-dynamics-webapi] [dynamics-crm-webapi]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[microsoft-dynamics-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-webapi) 36 Open Qs, 5 watchers

> A tag for questions related to the Microsoft Dynamics Web API. This tag should be used for questions about using the Web API in your code. Do not use this tag for questions related to using Microsoft Dynamics software (use the tag microsoft-dynamics instead). 
>   and

[dynamics-crm-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-webapi) 85 Open Qs, 6 watchers

> The Microsoft Dynamics 365 Web API (online & on-premises), provides a development experience that can be used across a wide variety of programming languages, platforms, and devices. The Web API implements the OData (Open Data Protocol), version 4.0, an OASIS standard for building and consuming RESTful APIs over rich data sources.

appear to relate to the same thing so it seems to make sense to combine these two tags.

Perhaps the tags should be merged to a tag called [dynamics-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-webapi)?

Microsoft has taken CRM out of the name for Microsoft Dynamics 365 so it would make sense to me to remove `crm` from the tag name.

However, I don't love [microsoft-dynamics-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-webapi) either since the other tags for dynamics exclude the `microsoft` portion (e.g. [dynamics-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav)).

---

[microsoft-dynamics-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-webapi) has been suggested as a synonym of [dynamics-crm-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-webapi) but its current score is `0`. There are enough qualified users to carry the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dynamics-crm-webapi/synonyms), once voted & approved it will get merged.

[dynamics-crm-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-webapi) makes more sense as the other primitive tags like [dynamics-crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm) is still being followed in SO.